# Send metadata with GCS signed url

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to set custom metadata to a file using when writing to a signed url? I tried adding a 'x-goog-meta-mything' but it didn't work. 
I'm using the node client lib.

Update to be clearer:

Setting the header doesn't seem to be an issue, but when creating the signed URL I have to know the value of the meta-data ahead of time, which isn't useful. I.E. I have `x-goog-meta-deltachanges` and it could be a number any where between 1 and many thousands. In my signedUrl I have to set `x-goog-meta-deltachanges:1,2,3,4,5,6...` and it doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

As far as the [Signed URLs docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) go, it should be.

Have you set the [Canonical extension headers](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#about-canonical-extension-headers) bit as needed?

I mean, you need to *both* include the `x-goog-meta-mything:VALUE` in the `StringToSign`, *and* you need to then send the same `x-goog-meta-mything:VALUE` header in the `PUT` request.

Have you done this, is it not working?

Comment: The thing is the `VALUE` is a changing variable, a number between 0 to some thousands. I tried this but I had to set all possible values in the extension headers. Is there a way to make a signed url that accepts any value, or a range of numbers or something?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.

Comment: My workaround right now is that I do `x-goog-meta-delta:abovethreshold,underthreshold`. Thanks for the help anyway